# R - How to transform a one-column dataframe to a ¿real? list

Tags: r

I have this data:

```
data <- structure(list(client_id = c("A", "B", 
"C", "D", "E", "F"
)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))
```

Where I need to match it with this `data_to_match`:

```
data_to_match <- structure(list(client_id = c("A", "E", "F"
)), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))
```

Such as:

```
data[data$client_id %in% data_to_match,] # returns empty
```

I have tried without success (which are the solutions to various questions here):

```
as.list(data_to_match)
list(data_to_match)
unlist(as.list(data_to_match))
```

But If I create a list from scratch it works perfectly:

```
data_to_match_created_as_list <- c("A", "E", "F")
data[data$client_id %in% data_to_match_created_as_list,] # it returns the right rows
```

At the end, my question is, how do I transform the `data_to_match` to a list like `data_to_match_created_as_list`?

In addition, how is the right name for this different types of list? I looked up for how to transform vector or one-column dataframe to list and the solutions are not equal to a list created from scratch (as in the example above and my multiple tries)

Comment: data_to_match_new<-data_to_match %>% unlist %>% unname() this is how I convert a 1 column dataframe to an unnamed vector

Comment: Your `data_to_match_created_as_list` is not a list, it's a vector. Would recommend reading up on data types in R, such as in [Advanced R](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Data-structures.html).

Comment: Have a look at [joins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299871/how-to-join-merge-data-frames-inner-outer-left-right), such as `dplyr::right_join(data, data_to_match, "client_id")`

Answer (score 1):

Why don't just using the name of the column (which will gives you a vector)?

```
data[data$client_id %in% data_to_match$client_id,]
```

or

```
data[data$client_id %in% data_to_match[[1]],]
```

**Output:**

```
# A tibble: 3 × 1
  client_id
  <chr>    
1 A        
2 E        
3 F
```

**Check:**

```
data[data$client_id %in% data_to_match$client_id,] == data[data$client_id %in% data_to_match_created_as_list,]

     client_id
[1,]      TRUE
[2,]      TRUE
[3,]      TRUE
```

Comment: Because I the name `client_id` can change.

Comment: Ok, but then you could use `data[data$client_id %in% data_to_match[[1]],]`, as the name doesn't matter in this way.

Answer (score 1):

While @Marco_CH answers works perfectly, if you just want an answer to the question:

> At the end, my question is, how do I transform the data_to_match to a list like data_to_match_created_as_list?

Applying **arrays** to the **unlisted** initial data to match will work:

```
array(unlist(data_to_match))
# [1] "A" "E" "F"
data[data$client_id %in% array(unlist(data_to_match)),]
# [1] "A" "E" "F"
```

Comment: Great solution (*upvote*). There is just one risk, if the data.frame gets two columns, isn't it? Than I think the second column will also be appended in the vector?

Comment: @Marco_CH  Yes indeed, but the question title is: R - How to transform a **one-column dataframe** to a ¿real? list. 
But sure, in a more general case, one should be careful, as you said, other columns would be appended.

Comment: You're right. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This question could be approached in different ways, depending on how many common columns the data have, what their structure is and what the expected output should look like.

If you want a **vector**

```
Reduce(intersect, c(data, data_to_match))
#> [1] "A" "E" "F"

unlist(c(data, data_to_match), use.names = F) |>
  (\(.) .[duplicated(.)])()
```

a **tibble**

```
dplyr::right_join(data, data_to_match, "client_id")
# A tibble: 3 x 1
  client_id
  <chr>    
1 A        
2 E        
3 F
```

or **matrix**

```
mapply(intersect, data, data_to_match)
     client_id
[1,] "A"      
[2,] "E"      
[3,] "F"
```